# There can only be one column for primary key made up of two columns one is autoincremented

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE license (
    driver SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    license_number SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    expirey_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (driver, license_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
```

Here I am getting the error

> Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one
> auto column and it must be defined as a key

I want to define the license number to be autoincremented and part of the primary key at the same time but it is not letting me.
My guessing is it because the primary key is a composite key made up of a foreign key as well.

Comment: If you use MyISAM you can have auto increment on a secondary column in the key. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. But this isn't possible with InnoDB.

Comment: Why do you think you *want* driver to be part of the primary key? Can two different users ever have the same license number? If not, license_number functions as a unique primary key for your table. 

Also I *strongly* recommend against using SMALLINTs for ids, since that caps you at 32767 records.

Comment: You could declare unique on the pair of columns, as well as primary key on the auto-increment